# Remove OWASP from pom file and use it in command line

Tags: devops, owasp-dependency-check

I have a requirement to run Owasp Dependency check in dev infra alone, not on UAT and PROD. Our M2 repo is hosted in a airgap infra.

Currently we have a OWASP plugin configured part of Pom file which works fine, but i need to remove from pom file and use it along with Maven command line.

is it supported? if not any other workaround please?

Comment: Any feedback? If the answer below solved your problem remember [to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any plugin can be run from the command line.  See [What is the syntax to run a maven plugin from the command line.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833919/what-is-the-syntax-to-run-a-maven-plugin-from-the-command-line)

In your case the syntax is:

```
mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:8.4.0:check
```

If you need to specify some cfg param, for example a suppression file, you can add a `-D` option:

```
-DsuppressionFiles=http://myhost/owasp/suppression.xml
```

The parameter names are the ones described in the [official documentation](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/configuration.html).